# problems with the Array tool using Fit curve

Tags: modifiers

I know this question has probably been answered before but I am having some frustrating problems with the array tool. when I select array using the Fit curve tool, nothing happens. I have attached a screenshot of the problem. Both the object and the circle have the same origin point. I am trying to get the object to follow the curve. [image]

Comment: A good place to start would be to make sure both the curve and the mesh have the same origin point.

Comment: Also make sure you applied the transforms with CTRL A > Apply Transforms and set the mean radius of the curve points to 1 in edit mode

Comment: thanks, i cant seem to quite get it right since im a beginner at it. But thanks anyways :)